# How to fix 'user input("User: ") syntaxerror'

Tags: python

I found a Python script I made around a year ago using Python 3. It worked fine a year ago but now it seems to have buggered itself up. I may have accidentally deleted something on accident.

Here is the entire script

```py
import time
import system

#Users

Users = {}
Users['---'] = "---"
Users['---'] = "---"

#Login

print("Booting system")
time.sleep(5)
user input("User: ")
if user in Users.keys():
    pass1 = input(Password: )
    if user in Users[user]:
        main()

#Options

def main():
    print("1) Placeholder")
    print("2) Placeholder")
    print("3) Exit")

    option = input("Enter option (1/2/3)")




    #Shutdown
    if option == '3':
        system.exit()

    #Placeholder
    if option == '1' or '2':
        print("Placeholder)


Here is the error


>     user input("User: ")
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why do you do this twice: `Users['---'] = "---"`
`Users['---'] = "---"`

Comment: `user = input("User: ")`? Might be time to refresh yourself a bit. :-)

Comment: `input(Password: )` also looks shady... as does `if option == '1' or '2':
        print("Placeholder)`. And `import sys` instead? The amount of errors—yikes.

Comment: Feel free to accept an answer if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 4):

**You're not assigning anything here!**

```
user input("User: ")
```

**Try this:**

```
user = input("User: ")
```

Other observations:

This will **NOT** work:

```
pass1 = input(Password: )
```

You need to wrap that string argument in quotes, like so:

```
pass1 = input("Password: ")
```

But on this note, consider using `getpass()` for your password input. This will cause the password to NOT be displayed in the console.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/getpass.html

```
import getpass

pass1 = getpass.getpass()
```